# UPDATE / INSERT from time to time takes few seconds

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I have problem with really simple INSERT / UPDATES on my server. From time to time it takes more than few second to finish query like this ones:

```
2.1062s - INSERT INTO `transaction` SET `idUser` = 72, `currency` = 50, `amount` = '10', `action` = 'buyCoins';
11.785s - UPDATE `user` SET `cash` = 10, `crystal` = 10, `expPoints` = 10, `energy` = 10 WHERE idUser = 72;
0.6296s - UPDATE `user` SET `lastEnergyUpdate` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE idUser = 72;
```

It looks like issue isn't depending on specific table. I don't have TRIGGERS on those tables.

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `idUser` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `expPoints` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `cash` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
 `crystal` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
 `energy` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `surname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `sex` enum('men','women','unknown') DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastEnergyUpdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastLogin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `insertDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`),
 UNIQUE KEY `serviceUnique` (`serviceName`,`serviceId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5333 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `idTransaction` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUser` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `currency` enum('crystal','partnerCurrency','cash') DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `action` enum('unlockPlace','buyExtra','collectReleased') NOT NULL,
  `insertDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`),
  KEY `fk_transaction_user1` (`idUser`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_transaction_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`) REFERENCES `user` (`idUser`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=156329 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

On same server I have more databases (~100) but nothing big. Dump of all databases is around 300MB.

Mysqltunner output:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.0.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.66-0ubuntu0.11.10.2-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: -Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 138M (Tables: 267)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 170M (Tables: 327)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 1)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 329

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 20h 45m 57s (558K q [7.468 qps], 58K conn, TX: 685M, RX: 98M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 66% / 34%
[--] Total buffers: 1.1G global + 6.0M per thread (150 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.0G (12% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (54/558K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 6% (10/150)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/8.8M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (245K cached / 258 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 51.5% (176K cached / 342K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 6% (1K temp sorts / 19K sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 34% (2K on disk / 8K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (10 created / 58K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 16% (786 open / 4K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 32% (714/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (329K immediate / 329K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 170.3M/512.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
    table_cache (> 1024)
```

Of course it happens only for ~1% of that queries (99% works fine), and then HDD is really bussy (13% - 20% wa on 8 cores server)

Should I keep increasing table_cache? Any other ideas what's going on? How can I improve it?

My MySQL Server is 5.1.66. I tried to upgrade to 5.5.x but that didn't help me, so I downgrade it back.

Comment: Have a look into slow-query-log, if there's a query that's locking tables and therefore blocking your upsert.

Comment: Your table cache hit rate is low (a good practical expectation is 95%+) and the cache size should probably be increased.  The amount of temp disk tables created is high, but that might just be because of the queries you're running; some will always require a temp disk table.  InnoDB can be fussy when inserting/updating data out of primary key order.  How many rows are there in the tables?  The foreign key might be part of the problem since it needs to be checked on insert/update.  Is there some reason the two update queries aren't one?

Comment: @tambom - I checked slow-query-log, but I found only those updates + some queries from different databases (but right now I care only about this database)

Comment: @G-Nugget - I'll increase cache, but what do you mean saying "a good practical expectation is 95%+". In transaction table I have ~150000 records, and in user ~4000 (but issue exists also with other tables, and like I mentioned I think it's not table related). Queries I provided are example - they come from different requests - that's why they are independent.

Comment: @Skowron I meant that 100% is ideal, but 95%+ is realistically good; If you open a few non-cached tables per hour it's fine.  I'm not seeing anything that would obviously slow down queries significantly.  I'm not sure of anything else that could easily fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Of course it happens only for ~1% of that queries (99% works fine), and then HDD is really bussy (13% - 20% was on 8 cores server)*

1. You are hitting a problem with your disk - I bet this occurs while your innodb log is flushing to disk - I would experiment with both smaller (for flushes more often) and larger log sizes (for less frequent flushes) - I expect you get more from more frequent flushes.
2. The other thing to see is what is eating your IO - run iotop during this time if you can to capture the culprit.
3. Otherwise, ensure your tmp, data, and log partitions are physically separate if you can.

Comment: 1. Good point. I will checkout solution with different innodb log size

2. iotop doesn't show anything - from time to time mysqld is on the to of the list but it disappears right after.

3. How big improvement this could be? I have all of them on one partition, but I think I could change that

Comment: 2 - it will only be effective if you run iotop while you are experiencing issues.
3. - can be huge, particularly if you use a raid10.